# Problema Wordpress, Manipulando imagens

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso fazer o seguinte, pegar o conteúdo de noticias e suas imagens de uma página e mostrar na pagina principal(obs as noticias atuais, e essa pagina não está no WP somente as outras) segue as imagens com a explicação detalhada

Essa é a pagina principal, aqui onde tem noticias cujo está com a imagem news tenho que mostrar as ultimas noticias das outras paginas que tem a imagem abaixo dessa

[image: ali onde tem news tenho que colocar as imagens das noticias e o link]

[image: Pegar essas noticias e imagens]

[image: e essas daqui entre outras paginas]

resumidamente: Tenho que pegar os links e imagens das noticias das outras paginas, e mostrar nesse index

obs: tive tentativas falhas pelo banco, utilizando essa função

```
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* FROM wp_3_posts wposts 
     LEFT JOIN wp_3_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN wp_3_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID =                            
     wp_3_term_relationships.object_id) 
     LEFT JOIN wp_3_term_taxonomy ON          
     (wp_3_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =          
     wp_3_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 

     union 
     SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* FROM wp_4_posts wposts 
     LEFT JOIN wp_4_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN wp_4_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID =          
     wp_4_term_relationships.object_id) 
     LEFT JOIN wp_4_term_taxonomy ON          
     (wp_4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 
     wp_4_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 

     union 
     SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* FROM wp_5_posts wposts 
     LEFT JOIN wp_5_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN wp_5_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID =          
     wp_5_term_relationships.object_id) 
     LEFT JOIN wp_5_term_taxonomy ON          
     (wp_5_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 
     wp_5_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)

     limit 6
     ");
```

adicionei um `WHERE post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'` e retornou imagens porém todas as imagens das paginas, tem um modo de eu pegar somente das categorias noticias?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc quer pegar parte do conteúdo de outras páginas para mostrar na inicial. Tipo as 6 últimas notícias publicadas irão aparecer na inicial. É isso?

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo Isso mesmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer a listagem de post de um determinado tipo ou categoria, você não precisa descer até o nível de criar um query em si. O wp tem funções que abstraem isso. Tudo isso pode ser feito usando a classe [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

### O uso básico da classe WP_Query:

```
<?php

    // Inicialização do objeto WP_Query com os parâmetros da busca($args)
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // O loop para percorrer os resultados da query
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'Sem conteúdo!';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Como no wp, por trás, tudo são posts, com o uso dessa classe é possível fazer busca por [posts de uma categoria específica](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters), [páginas](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters), [imagens ou arquivos inseridos](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#mime-type-parameters), [tipos de posts customizados](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters), etc.

### Outras alternativas

- [wp_get_recent_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) : Uma possibilidade um pouco mais alto nível que WP_Query, que permite um código mais simples e direto. Exemplo de uso:

  ```
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
  foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
      echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
  }
  wp_reset_query();
  ```
- [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) : Muito parecida com a anterior, apresentando mais parâmetros de busca, consequentemente, mais flexibilidade e abrangência. Exemplo de uso:

  ```
  <?php
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
  $postslist = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
      setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
      <div>
          <?php the_date(); ?>
          <br />
          <?php the_title(); ?>   
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>
  <?php
      endforeach; 
      wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  ```

OBS: Exemplos retirados da documentação.